# Dealing with Inverse Kinematics - End of "Leg" Moves the Entire Model

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature

*3rd 'paragraph' is where I have stated my issue. Before is context/what I've done so far
I've been scouring forums for the past hour or so and haven't been able to come across a solution that seems to help my problem. Essentially what I'm trying to do is make the foot of an "ant" move only the leg. See images below. (I can only do two links so I figured the two attached were the more important ones)

The issue I'm having is that when I try to make the end of the leg an IK bone (SHIFT + I), it bounds to the tail-end of the ant. May help to note this is the bone I started my armature on. See second image for those bones.[image: The bones I referred to have beenare circled]

So... context provided... Whenever I try to move this IK bone, the entire model moves, pivoting around the tail-end bone (circled above). I've tried reparenting the bone, disconnecting the armature, and a few other things that are workarounds of those. All I want it to move is the leg, circled in this image. Also note this was moved, pivoting around the tail-end bone as stated, from moving only the IK bone. [image: Leg I want to move]

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, apologies if this has a simple solution I've overlooked. Perhaps I've simply messed up the armature.
Thanks in advance,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the IK bone constraint and check the chain length. The default is 0, meaning that the whole chain is included. Set it instead to the number of bones in the leg. [Here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/tracking/ik_solver.html) is the documentation.

Comment: That would be it, much appreciated!